# hello Everyone i am new in wordpress and i am facing one issue with plugins installation can any one suugest me how this error solve

Tags: wordpress

Downloading install package from http://demo.cms-theme.net/wordpress/plugins/cmstheme.v3.zip…

Download failed. cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds

Comment: What about the file size? maybe a bandwidth related issue?

Comment: I suggest you to get the code that is raising the error, or the error log from PHP, and then paste it here, this isn't enough info.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded the file and it worked fine. Do you mean it will not upload to wordpress?

Its available here if you need another place to download from https://ufile.io/0c8ed